# Access to returned prototype functions inside another function

Tags: javascript

How would i access the klass.prototype.init function from the global window? This exmaple is from javascript web applciations (orielly).

```
var Class = function(){ 
    var klass = function(){
            this.init.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log("here");
    };
    klass.prototype.init = function(){
        console.log("another");
    };
    return klass; 
};

window.Person = new Class;
```

executing Person() will log "here" to the console. I tried accessing the prototype by using Person.klass.init() with no success.

Can someone supplement another way of explaining this? The book says "we could return a function that would set up a new class, the first step in building our own class emulation library:"

Comment: `window.Person.prototype.init`?

Comment: @Bergi: I think u need to add `()` at he end, as it should be a function.

Comment: Yes that works - why couldn't we access it as window.person.klass.init?

Comment: @rockStar: access, not invoke.

Comment: @seasick: Because `window.Person == klass` (apart from the different scopes). There is no `klass` property of anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would i access the klass.prototype.init function

By `window.Person.prototype.init`.

`klass` is what is `return`ed from `Class()`, and is *assigned* to `window.Person`. Btw you shouldn't use `new` with `Class` here.

Comment: When inovking Person() , why is prototype.init not invoked as well? I get an error saying that i can't call method of undefined

Comment: `this.init()` inside the constructor works. `this.prototype` does not. Not sure what exactly you're doing.