# Access the parameter of a function from another function in javascript / typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, formik

How can I access the parameter of a lambda function from another function?

I'm trying to access the value of `formikBag`, created inside `render={...}`, from the `handleClick` function.

I first tried with `useState` hook to set the state and later access it, but I get `undefined`.

```
export const Form: React.FC<FormProps> = (props) => {   
    const MyFormikForm = () => {
        return (
            <Formik
                initialValues={...}
                onSubmit={...)
                validationSchema={.}
                render={(formikBag: FormikProps<FormValues>) => <form>My Form</form>}
            />
        )
    }

    const handleClick = () => {
        showModal(({ show }) => {
            // How could I get access the formikBag variable here?                          

            // do stuff
            return (
                <ModalAntd>
                    <MyFormikForm />
                </ModalAntd>
            )
        })
    }

    return <ButtonComponent onClick={handleClick} />
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you use formikBag?

Comment: `formikBag` is an object that contains different methods and fields to act upon your `formik` form. I need access to `formikBag.submitForm`, and `formikBag.isSubmitting` inside the handleClick function. Eg: `isSubmitting` helps me with button styling while the form is submitting. I'm putting together a component that will either display a `form`, or a `button` that will display a modal form. I simplified my code to the max

Comment: You can assign things you need (methods or entire formikBag) to useRef ref and access it in handleClick. This is not a clean way but it will work.

Comment: I'll try that. Could you explain briefly why it isn't a clean way, and if there is a cleaner way? Thank you!

Comment: Because this requires to communicate between callbacks (render and showModal) in awkward way. I'd say that using a HOC (withFormik) results in better structured components, then you could communicate between them through common parent. As for react-use-modal hook you're using, it doesn't seem like a good thing at all to me just because it requires callbacks causes problems like this one. I can't recommend how the code can be improved as long as you're using react-use-modal.

Comment: OK. I'll try to get something working as is with `useRef`, then refactor to use `withFormik`. I can see how this would simplify the code. Thanks again

Comment: Before you do that, what is your overall objective here? I can't think of a reason why want to access the Formik bag outside of the form itself, so maybe there is a simpler way of doing what you're trying.

Comment: I'm building a component that either shows a form directly, or wraps it inside a `Button` that triggers a modal form. When using the modal form, (using `antd` `Modal` component), I can customize the `Modal`'s buttons. I'd like to use the ones from 'Formik''s form instead of antd's modal, or at least get access to the formikBag, so I can use  methods such as `isSubmitting` to prevent users to submit again while reaching the server, or even making sure all the fields are valid before I can click on the button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access to returned prototype functions inside another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940959/access-to-returned-prototype-functions-inside-another-function)

Comment: I think I almost understand your use case, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rearrange your component hierarchy to do this properly. By wrapping your modal in the `Formik` component (rather than the other way around) you can access the Formik bag or anything else you need.

I'm not completely sure I fully understand what you're doing but I think this is close:

```
/**
 * Form that can appear in a modal or directly.
 */
function ExampleForm({
  isSubmitting,
  showButton
}: {
  isSubmitting: boolean;
  showButton: boolean;
}) {
  return (
    <Form>
      <label htmlFor="field">Some Field</label>
      <Field name="field" type="text" />
      {showButton && (
        <Button loading={isSubmitting} htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      )}
    </Form>
  );
}

/**
 * Show a form in a modal or directly.
 */
class ExampleFormWrapper extends React.PureComponent<
  { showModal: boolean },
  { isOpen: boolean }
> {
  state = { isOpen: false };

  /**
   * Close the modal form.
   */
  hideForm = () => this.setState({ isOpen: false });

  /**
   * Open the form in a modal.
   */
  openForm = () => this.setState({ isOpen: true });

  /**
   * Submit the form with fake wait to simulate a real submission.
   */
  onSubmit = (
    values: FormValues,
    { setSubmitting }: FormikActions<FormValues>
  ) => {
    console.log(values);
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.props.showModal) {
        this.hideForm();
      } else {
        setSubmitting(false);
      }
    }, 2000);
  };

  /**
   * Render either a form or a button that will show the form in a modal.
   */
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.props.showModal && <Button onClick={this.openForm}>Open</Button>}
        <Formik initialValues={{ field: "" }} onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          {({ handleSubmit, isSubmitting }) =>
            this.props.showModal ? (
              <Modal
                onCancel={this.hideForm}
                onOk={handleSubmit}
                okButtonProps={{ loading: isSubmitting }}
                okText="Submit"
                title="Form"
                visible={this.state.isOpen}
              >
                <ExampleForm isSubmitting={isSubmitting} showButton={false} />
              </Modal>
            ) : (
              <ExampleForm isSubmitting={isSubmitting} showButton={true} />
            )
          }
        </Formik>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

[Here it is working on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pw2w4v7680).

I've never used Ant before but the design of their modal component makes this more difficult that it should be.

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you so much for taking the time to make a working example of such quality. My downfall was using `useModal`, it made me overthink instead of going for what you did.